# Export .rdlc report to pdf in Landscape mode

Tags: javascript, .net, pdf, reporting-services, report-viewer2012

My report properties are set to Width 11in and Height 8.5in. My body properties are set to Width 10in and Height 7.5in and the margins are 0, but the report always displays in portrait mode. The person who coded the page is using a reportviewer control inside of an aspx page which is being popped up from a JavaScript pop window writing the response to a pdf. If the report is opened in the report viewer it is landscape like expected. Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

width, height and orientation of a Report (.rdlc) depends on the two factors :

1. What page settings are applied on the report. We can set orientation to landscape by opening report[image: Select Report and Orientation] in Solution Explorer
2. Adding Some line of codes to define width, height and orientation.

```
Function SetPageSettings()
    Dim PgSet As New System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings
    Dim Psiz As New Printing.PaperSize
    Psiz.RawKind = Printing.PaperKind.A4
    PgSet.PaperSize = Psiz
    PgSet.Landscape = False
    PgSet.Margins.Top = 60
    PgSet.Margins.Bottom = 60
    PgSet.Margins.Right = 60
    PgSet.Margins.Left = 60
    ReportViewer1.SetPageSettings(PgSet)
End Function
```

Comment: After setting Orientation, Your report can be saved as pdf,xls or doc file in that orientation.